# Official client verification - how does it work?

Tags: security, authentication, ssl, certificate, verification

I was thinking about a way to ensure that the authenticated client (by username, password, OAuth) is using the official client, and not a third side one which sends requests to the server, assuming that the official client can be decompiled and the code is revealed.

What's the best solution for this security problem?
I have been reading about digital signature and SSL certificates but I cannot find how it solves this problem.

Hope to find a good answer, thanks!

Comment: #youcanneverbesure. Basically it comes down to the determination of the person who wants to provide a third party service.

Comment: @Tschallacka If so, there is no way to provide a service to a client, while being sure that only the official client uses it? For example, don't  game servers verify if the client which is used by the players is genuine and official?

Comment: just google hacker + some game and watch the videos. You can never be sure, just make it difficult